# Can I share predefined fonts from theme_support with a gutenberg component?

Tags: plugins, themes, javascript, block-editor, fonts

I have a few fonts defined in my `functions.php`:

```php
        add_theme_support('editor-font-sizes', array(
            array(
                'name' => esc_attr__('Small', 'moderna'),
                'size' => 13,
                'slug' => 'small'
            ),
            ......
            array(
                'name' => esc_attr__('Headline', 'moderna'),
                'size' => 40,
                'slug' => 'headline'
            )
        ));
```

I want to use these defined fonts now in a **FontSizePicker Component** from Gutenberg. However I do not want to define these two times. Is there any way to get these fonts from php to the wordpress block?

```js
<InspectorControls>
  <FontSizePicker
    fontSizes={GET_FONTS_FROM_THEME_SUPPORT()}
    value={26}
    fallbackFontSize={12}
    onChange={(newFontSize) => console.log(newFontSize)}
    withSlider
  />
</InspectorControls>;
```

Comment: At the color components you can leave the "color" value away than it will use the defaults. Maybe this is working here as well...

Answer (score 1):

A better way to use fontSizes

```
/**
 * WordPress dependencies
 */
import { FontSizePicker } from '@wordpress/components';
import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';

const Edit = ( { attributes, setAttributes } ) => {

    
    // Get fontSizes from the core/block-editor settings
    const { fontSizes } = useSelect( ( select ) => {
        return select( 'core/block-editor' ).getSettings();
    }, [] );
    const fontSizeFallback = 16;

    return (
        <>
            <InspectorControls>                 
                    <FontSizePicker
                        fontSizes={ fontSizes }
                        fallbackFontSize={ fontSizeFallback }
                        value={ attributes.fontSize }
                        onChange={ (size) => setAttributes({ fontSize: size }) }
                        withSlider
                    />
            </InspectorControls>
            // Your code here
        </>
    );
}

export default Edit;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but for anyone looking for an answer here it is:

You can find all of the settings already defined by php within the window.wp.data object so within an addFilter callback function you can get that data that you’re looking for like so:

```
const { useSelect } = wp.data;
const { addFilter } = wp.hooks;
const blockEdit = createHigherOrderComponent(BlockEdit => (props) => {
    const { fontSizes, colors } = useSelect(select => select('core/block-editor').getSettings());
    console.log(fontSizes, colors);
});
addFilter('editor.BlockEdit', 'namespace/controlsBlockEdit', blockEdit);
```